# How to Bootstrap Express Server together with GRPC Server on Cloud Run using Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, grpc, google-cloud-run

I have a NodeJS Server that houses two servers in one process.

```
//This function immediately starts the express server
async startExpressServer() {
    const app=express();
    const port = 3000;
    app.listen(port, async function () {
        console.log(`Express Service running on port ${port} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode`);
    });
}

//This function immediately starts the gRPC server
async startGRPCServer(){
    let port = 4000;
    grpcServer.bindAsync(`0.0.0.0:${port}`, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), 
     () 
     => {
        grpcServer.start();
        console.log(`GRPC Server running on ${port}`);
    });
}
```

Since cloud run exposes just a single port per service instance, I attempted to proxy the ports of the above servers using nginx with the following nginx configurations in my `nginx.conf` file which is sitting at the root of my project:

```
upstream grpc-server {
     server 0.0.0.0:4000;
}

server {

    listen       $PORT;
    server_name  customer-service;

    location /customer{ # Send requests on this route to the grpc server
        grpc_pass  grpcs://grpc-server; 
    }

    location /v1 { # Send requests on this route to the express server
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000; 
    }
    
}
```

And below is the script I have in my `Dockerfile` to start the app as a whole

```
FROM node:18-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . ./

# server environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template

CMD sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;' && node server.js"
```

When I deployed the app to cloud run the app refuse to run. I have a very strong feeling certain configurations above are not correct, please I would appreciate any corrections and or suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expose 2 ports in cloudrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73616292/how-to-expose-2-ports-in-cloudrun)

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB yes it answers the question but it doesn't solve it. I had to dump gRPC and use plain REST at the end of the day since no matter what, I am not allowed to run multiple containers in one service in Cloud Run. Thanks